# Inconsistent Behavior with Similar Insertion Sort Functions in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector, insertion-sort

I'm experiencing an issue with two similar insertion sort functions in C++. Both functions are intended to sort a vector of string-character pairs based on the character value in ascending order. The first function `insertionSort1` produces the expected sorted output, but the second function `insertionSort2`, which only differs by the placement of the decrement operation `j--`, gives an unexpected and incorrect result.

Below is the code snippet that demonstrates both sorting functions and their respective outputs. The only difference between the two functions is that in `insertionSort2`, `j--` is combined with the assignment statement, while in `insertionSort1`, it is separated onto its own line.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void insertionSort1(vector<pair<string,char>>&v) {
  for (int i=1; i<v.size(); i++) {
    auto curr=v[i];
    int j=i-1;
    while(j>=0 && curr.second<v[j].second) {v[j+1]=v[j]; v[j--];}
    v[j+1] = curr;
  }
}

void insertionSort2(vector<pair<string,char>>&v) {
  for (int i=1; i<v.size(); i++) {
    auto curr=v[i];
    int j=i-1;
    while(j>=0 && curr.second<v[j].second) {v[j+1]=v[j--];}
    v[j+1] = curr;
  }
}

int main() {
  vector<pair<string, char>> v1 {
    {"Alice"  , 'B'},
    {"Bob"    , 'A'},
    {"Charlie", 'B'},
    {"David"  , 'A'}
  };
  // Print the original vector
  for(auto i : v1) cout << "{" << i.first << ", " << i.second << "} "; cout << endl; // {Alice, B} {Bob, A} {Charlie, B} {David, A}
  // Sort the vector
  insertionSort1(v1);
  // Print the sorted vector
  for(auto i : v1) cout << "{" << i.first << ", " << i.second << "} "; cout << endl; // {Bob, A} {David, A} {Alice, B} {Charlie, B}
  
  cout << "///////////////////////////////////////////\n";
  
  vector<pair<string, char>> v2 {
    {"Alice"  , 'B'},
    {"Bob"    , 'A'},
    {"Charlie", 'B'},
    {"David"  , 'A'}
  };
  // Print the original vector
  for(auto i : v2) cout << "{" << i.first << ", " << i.second << "} "; cout << endl; // {Alice, B} {Bob, A} {Charlie, B} {David, A}
  // Sort the vector
  insertionSort2(v2);
  // Print the sorted vector
  for(auto i : v2) cout << "{" << i.first << ", " << i.second << "} "; cout << endl; // {Bob, A} {Bob, A} {David, A} {David, A} // Unexpected output occurs here!
  return 0;
}
```

The expected sorted output for both vectors should be: `{Bob, A} {David, A} {Alice, B} {Charlie, B}`

However, the actual output I'm getting after using insertionSort2 is incorrect: `{Bob, A} {Bob, A} {David, A} {David, A}`

Why does insertionSort2 produce an incorrect result when it seemingly only has a minor syntactic difference from insertionSort1, which works as expected?

---

@tbxfreeware
`If possible, Taher, please post a program that demonstrates that there is no problem with integer data.`

````cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void insertionSort1(vector<int>&v) {
  for (int i=1; i<v.size(); i++) {
    auto curr=v[i];
    int j=i-1;
    while(j>=0 && curr<v[j]) {v[j+1]=v[j]; v[j--];}
    v[j+1] = curr;
  }
}

void insertionSort2(vector<int>&v) {
  for (int i=1; i<v.size(); i++) {
    auto curr=v[i];
    int j=i-1;
    while(j>=0 && curr<v[j]) {v[j+1]=v[j--];}
    v[j+1] = curr;
  }
}

int main() {
  vector<int> v1 {7, 4, 1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 5};
  for(auto i : v1) cout << i << " "; cout << endl; // 7 4 1 2 3 6 9 8 5
  insertionSort1(v1);
  for(auto i : v1) cout << i << " "; cout << endl; // 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  
  cout << "//////////////////\n";
  
  vector<int> v2 {7, 4, 1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 5};
  for(auto i : v2) cout << i << " "; cout << endl; // 7 4 1 2 3 6 9 8 5
  insertionSort2(v2);
  for(auto i : v2) cout << i << " "; cout << endl; // 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  return 0;
}```
````

Comment: Use a debugger to go step by step and check the variable values. Or add some log when the elements swapped.

Comment: As of C++17, the assignment expression `v[j+1]=v[j--];` is guaranteed to evaluate the right side of the assignment, including the side-effect to variable `j`, prior to any evaluation of the left side. Prior to C++17, evaluation order was unspecified.

Comment: That's an interesting point regarding the evaluation order in C++17. However, I've observed that when dealing with a vector of integers using the same insertionSort2 function, the issue does not occur, and the sorting behaves as expected. It's peculiar that this unexpected behavior only manifests with a vector of pairs. Could there be another explanation for why this specific problem is occurring with pairs, and not with other data types like integers?

Comment: Are you compiling under C++17 or later when you get the inconsistent result that integers work but pairs don't? If you are using an earlier standard, then we could chalk it up to UB.

Comment: @tbxfreeware c++23 in vscode

Comment: @TaherAnaya VS Code is not a compiler, it's an editor. Since it is also annoyingly difficult to configure correctly: what exactly is your compiler and your compilation command?

Comment: @TaherAnaya You haven't tested very thoroughly with integers. Sorting `{2,1}` with `insertionSort2` gives `1, 1`.

Comment: And sorting the equivalently disordered (i.e. as in your pair case) `{2,1,2,1}` results in `{1,1,1,1}`.

Comment: [don't use `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/995714) and [**never use `bits/stdc++.h`**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/995714)

Answer (score 2):

Under C++17 and later, the right side of an assignment expression is guaranteed to be evaluated completely, including all side-effects, prior to any evaluation of the left side. See: [Refining Expression Evaluation Order for Idiomatic C++](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0145r3.pdf) by Gabriel Dos Reis, Herb Sutter, and Jonathan Caves.

Consider then, the first assignment (i.e., move right), when:

- `i` == 1
- `j` == 0
- `j + 1` == 1

You want `v[0]` to be copied into `v[1]`, using the expression `v[j + 1] = v[j--];`

What happens, however, is that `j` is decremented before `j + 1` is evaluated.

- original value of `j` == 0
- decremented value of `j` == -1
- decremented value of `j` + 1 == 0

So instead of copying `v[0]` into `v[1]`, it is copied back to `v[0]`, and `v[1]` remains unaltered.

At this point, `j` has the value -1, which causes the "j-loop" to end. Afterwards, variable `curr`, which came from `v[1]` (and which is still stored there because of the failure to overwrite `v[1]` above), is stored at `v[j + 1]`, which is `v[0]`.

So, `curr` is stored in two places: `v[0]` and `v[1]`. The data originally stored at `v[0]` was overwritten, and is lost. You can see this in the output below, in the line marked `is2, after  j-loop: i: 1, j: -1`:

```
is2, after  j-loop: i: 1, j: -1, v: [{"Bob",'A'},{"Bob",'A'},{"Charlie",'B'},{"David",'A'}]
```

If the decrement is moved to the left side of the assignment, as in `insertionSort3`, below, then the sort works correctly.

```cpp
void insertionSort3(vector<pair<string, char>>& v) {
    for (int i = 1; i < v.size(); i++) {
        auto curr = v[i];
        int j = i - 1;
        while (j >= 0 && curr.second < v[j].second) { v[j-- + 1] = v[j]; }
        v[j + 1] = curr;
    }
}
```

##### Expanded Output

This data was generated using the program from the next section. It verifies the overwrite that was predicted in the foregoing analysis.

```
{Alice, B} {Bob, A} {Charlie, B} {David, A}

is1, before j-loop: i: 1, j: 0, v: [{"Alice",'B'},{"Bob",'A'},{"Charlie",'B'},{"David",'A'}]
is1, inside j-loop: i: 1, j: -1, v: [{"Alice",'B'},{"Alice",'B'},{"Charlie",'B'},{"David",'A'}]
is1, after  j-loop: i: 1, j: -1, v: [{"Bob",'A'},{"Alice",'B'},{"Charlie",'B'},{"David",'A'}]

is1, before j-loop: i: 2, j: 1, v: [{"Bob",'A'},{"Alice",'B'},{"Charlie",'B'},{"David",'A'}]
is1, after  j-loop: i: 2, j: 1, v: [{"Bob",'A'},{"Alice",'B'},{"Charlie",'B'},{"David",'A'}]

is1, before j-loop: i: 3, j: 2, v: [{"Bob",'A'},{"Alice",'B'},{"Charlie",'B'},{"David",'A'}]
is1, inside j-loop: i: 3, j: 1, v: [{"Bob",'A'},{"Alice",'B'},{"Charlie",'B'},{"Charlie",'B'}]
is1, inside j-loop: i: 3, j: 0, v: [{"Bob",'A'},{"Alice",'B'},{"Alice",'B'},{"Charlie",'B'}]
is1, after  j-loop: i: 3, j: 0, v: [{"Bob",'A'},{"David",'A'},{"Alice",'B'},{"Charlie",'B'}]
{Bob, A} {David, A} {Alice, B} {Charlie, B}
///////////////////////////////////////////
{Alice, B} {Bob, A} {Charlie, B} {David, A}

is2, before j-loop: i: 1, j: 0, v: [{"Alice",'B'},{"Bob",'A'},{"Charlie",'B'},{"David",'A'}]
is2, inside j-loop: i: 1, j: -1, v: [{"Alice",'B'},{"Bob",'A'},{"Charlie",'B'},{"David",'A'}]
is2, after  j-loop: i: 1, j: -1, v: [{"Bob",'A'},{"Bob",'A'},{"Charlie",'B'},{"David",'A'}]

is2, before j-loop: i: 2, j: 1, v: [{"Bob",'A'},{"Bob",'A'},{"Charlie",'B'},{"David",'A'}]
is2, after  j-loop: i: 2, j: 1, v: [{"Bob",'A'},{"Bob",'A'},{"Charlie",'B'},{"David",'A'}]

is2, before j-loop: i: 3, j: 2, v: [{"Bob",'A'},{"Bob",'A'},{"Charlie",'B'},{"David",'A'}]
is2, inside j-loop: i: 3, j: 1, v: [{"Bob",'A'},{"Bob",'A'},{"Charlie",'B'},{"David",'A'}]
is2, after  j-loop: i: 3, j: 1, v: [{"Bob",'A'},{"Bob",'A'},{"David",'A'},{"David",'A'}]
{Bob, A} {Bob, A} {David, A} {David, A}
///////////////////////////////////////////
{Alice, B} {Bob, A} {Charlie, B} {David, A}

is3, before j-loop: i: 1, j: 0, v: [{"Alice",'B'},{"Bob",'A'},{"Charlie",'B'},{"David",'A'}]
is3, inside j-loop: i: 1, j: -1, v: [{"Alice",'B'},{"Alice",'B'},{"Charlie",'B'},{"David",'A'}]
is3, after  j-loop: i: 1, j: -1, v: [{"Bob",'A'},{"Alice",'B'},{"Charlie",'B'},{"David",'A'}]

is3, before j-loop: i: 2, j: 1, v: [{"Bob",'A'},{"Alice",'B'},{"Charlie",'B'},{"David",'A'}]
is3, after  j-loop: i: 2, j: 1, v: [{"Bob",'A'},{"Alice",'B'},{"Charlie",'B'},{"David",'A'}]

is3, before j-loop: i: 3, j: 2, v: [{"Bob",'A'},{"Alice",'B'},{"Charlie",'B'},{"David",'A'}]
is3, inside j-loop: i: 3, j: 1, v: [{"Bob",'A'},{"Alice",'B'},{"Charlie",'B'},{"Charlie",'B'}]
is3, inside j-loop: i: 3, j: 0, v: [{"Bob",'A'},{"Alice",'B'},{"Alice",'B'},{"Charlie",'B'}]
is3, after  j-loop: i: 3, j: 0, v: [{"Bob",'A'},{"David",'A'},{"Alice",'B'},{"Charlie",'B'}]
{Bob, A} {David, A} {Alice, B} {Charlie, B}
```

##### Output operators / debug routine

This program has been adapted from the OP. It adds output operators and a debug function that simplify the task of watching the sorting steps.

```cpp
// main.cpp

//#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::pair;
using std::string;
using std::vector;

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ost, std::pair<std::string, char> const& p)
{
    ost << '{' << std::quoted(p.first) << ",'" << p.second << "'}";
    return ost;
}
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& ost, vector<pair<string, char>> const& v)
{
    ost.put('[');
    if (!v.empty())
    {
        auto n_commas{ v.size() - 1u };
        for (std::size_t i{}; i < n_commas; ++i)
            ost << v[i] << ',';
        ost << v.back();
    }
    ost.put(']');
    return ost;
}
void debug(
    std::string const& heading, 
    int const i, 
    int const j, 
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, char>>& v)
{
    std::cout << heading << ": " 
        << "i: " << i
        << ", j: " << j
        << ", v: "<< v 
        << '\n';
}

void insertionSort1(vector<pair<string, char>>& v) {
    for (int i = 1; i < v.size(); i++) {
        auto curr = v[i];
        int j = i - 1;
        debug("\nis1, before j-loop", i, j, v);
        while (j >= 0 && curr.second < v[j].second) { 
            v[j + 1] = v[j]; v[j--];
            debug("is1, inside j-loop", i, j, v);
        }
        v[j + 1] = curr;
        debug("is1, after  j-loop", i, j, v);
    }
}

void insertionSort2(vector<pair<string, char>>& v) {
    for (int i = 1; i < v.size(); i++) {
        auto curr = v[i];
        int j = i - 1;
        debug("\nis2, before j-loop", i, j, v);
        while (j >= 0 && curr.second < v[j].second) {
            v[j + 1] = v[j--];
            debug("is2, inside j-loop", i, j, v);
        }
        v[j + 1] = curr;
        debug("is2, after  j-loop", i, j, v);
    }
}

void insertionSort3(vector<pair<string, char>>& v) {
    for (int i = 1; i < v.size(); i++) {
        auto curr = v[i];
        int j = i - 1;
        debug("\nis3, before j-loop", i, j, v);
        while (j >= 0 && curr.second < v[j].second) { 
            v[j-- + 1] = v[j]; 
            debug("is3, inside j-loop", i, j, v);
        }
        v[j + 1] = curr;
        debug("is3, after  j-loop", i, j, v);
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<pair<string, char>> v1{
      {"Alice"  , 'B'},
      {"Bob"    , 'A'},
      {"Charlie", 'B'},
      {"David"  , 'A'}
    };
    // Print the original vector
    for (auto i : v1) cout << "{" << i.first << ", " << i.second << "} "; cout << endl; // {Alice, B} {Bob, A} {Charlie, B} {David, A}
    // Sort the vector
    insertionSort1(v1);
    // Print the sorted vector
    for (auto i : v1) cout << "{" << i.first << ", " << i.second << "} "; cout << endl; // {Bob, A} {David, A} {Alice, B} {Charlie, B}

    cout << "///////////////////////////////////////////\n";

    vector<pair<string, char>> v2{
      {"Alice"  , 'B'},
      {"Bob"    , 'A'},
      {"Charlie", 'B'},
      {"David"  , 'A'}
    };
    // Print the original vector
    for (auto i : v2) cout << "{" << i.first << ", " << i.second << "} "; cout << endl; // {Alice, B} {Bob, A} {Charlie, B} {David, A}
    // Sort the vector
    insertionSort2(v2);
    // Print the sorted vector
    for (auto i : v2) cout << "{" << i.first << ", " << i.second << "} "; cout << endl; // {Bob, A} {Bob, A} {David, A} {David, A} // Unexpected output occurs here!

    cout << "///////////////////////////////////////////\n";

    vector<pair<string, char>> v3{
      {"Alice"  , 'B'},
      {"Bob"    , 'A'},
      {"Charlie", 'B'},
      {"David"  , 'A'}
    };
    // Print the original vector
    for (auto i : v3) cout << "{" << i.first << ", " << i.second << "} "; cout << endl; // {Alice, B} {Bob, A} {Charlie, B} {David, A}
    // Sort the vector
    insertionSort3(v3);
    // Print the sorted vector
    for (auto i : v3) cout << "{" << i.first << ", " << i.second << "} "; cout << endl; // {Bob, A} {Bob, A} {David, A} {David, A} // Unexpected output occurs here!

    return 0;
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

##### What about integers?

@Taher Anaya, the OP, reports that the problem only occurs when sorting pairs, and specifically, that it does not occur when sorting integers. I have no explanation for this. The analysis above indicates it should affect any objects that are sorted using `insertionSort2`.

The mystery to me is not that `insertionSort2` fails to sort pairs, but rather that it succeeds in sorting anything.

If possible, Taher, please post a program that demonstrates that there is no problem with integer data.

*[Edit:]* Thank you, Taher, for [posting a program](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78034683/22193627). Unfortunately, I am not able to coroborate your results. When I ran your program under MSVC (/std:c++latest), I got output that shows overwritten data, similar to what was seen (and expected) with pairs.

```
7 4 1 2 3 6 9 8 5
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
//////////////////
7 4 1 2 3 6 9 8 5
1 4 1 2 3 5 8 8 5    <--------- scads of bad data!
```

This is the same result that @molbdnilo recorded from his [run on coliru.stacked-crooked.com](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/56d34a58a8f5d556).